# Are there any working examples of ogrlineref?

Tags: gdal, ogr, linear-referencing

I'd like to understand how `ogrlineref` works but I can't find any examples.  I'd like to see the actual "roads.shp" and "references.shp" mentioned in the example invocation:

> ogrlineref -create -l roads.shp -p references.shp -pm dist -o parts.shp -s 1000 -progress

Specifically, I'm unclear on LRS in general and what "dist" column represent in this case.  Isn't this tool supposed to produce those values?

> -pmpos_field_name: The field name of distances along path (e.g. mile-stones values)

After this question was answered I converted the shp files to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr:

paths.json

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "path",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "name": "test" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.449095097755853, 51.912769864393873 ], [ -1.446702601405906, 51.915640860013809 ], [ -1.44742035031089, 51.917554857093762 ], [ -1.444549354690954, 51.923057598698641 ], [ -1.44383160578597, 51.928321090668526 ], [ -1.441199859801029, 51.935020080448375 ], [ -1.439764361991061, 51.941240570958236 ], [ -1.437371865641115, 51.946504062928113 ], [ -1.43402237075119, 51.951767554897998 ], [ -1.431390624766249, 51.955117049787923 ], [ -1.428998128416302, 51.960859041027796 ], [ -1.431629874401244, 51.964687035187708 ], [ -1.43043362622627, 51.966840281902662 ], [ -1.438568113816088, 51.976410267302448 ] ] } }
]
}
```

mstones.json

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "mstones",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 18900.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.43761111527611, 51.975214019127471 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 18100.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.432108373671233, 51.968754278982615 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 16900.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.430194376591276, 51.958466544677847 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 15900.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.435697118196153, 51.94937505854805 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 14900.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.440003611626056, 51.940044322783258 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 13700.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.443592356150976, 51.929517338843496 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "pos": 12100.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.447659599945885, 51.917076357823774 ] } }
]
}
```

parts.json

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "parts",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 11759.13883732543, "end": 12000.0, "scale": 9.443966948e-06 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.449095097755853, 51.912769864393873 ], [ -1.449095097755853, 51.912769864393873 ], [ -1.447638879994777, 51.914517325707166 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 12000.0, "end": 13000.0, "scale": 9.443966948e-06 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.447638879994777, 51.914517325707166 ], [ -1.446702601405906, 51.915640860013809 ], [ -1.44742035031089, 51.917554857093762 ], [ -1.444673955650802, 51.922818780192266 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 13000.0, "end": 14000.0, "scale": 9.443966948e-06 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.444673955650802, 51.922818780192266 ], [ -1.444549354690954, 51.923057598698641 ], [ -1.44383160578597, 51.928321090668526 ], [ -1.44241931228486, 51.931916019580441 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 14000.0, "end": 15000.0, "scale": 9.542439841e-06 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.44241931228486, 51.931916019580441 ], [ -1.441199859801029, 51.935020080448375 ], [ -1.439804059060893, 51.941068550322299 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 15000.0, "end": 16000.0, "scale": 1.0428695878e-05 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.439804059060893, 51.941068550322299 ], [ -1.439764361991061, 51.941240570958236 ], [ -1.437371865641115, 51.946504062928113 ], [ -1.434971803727003, 51.950275588793147 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 16000.0, "end": 17000.0, "scale": 1.0428695878e-05 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.434971803727003, 51.950275588793147 ], [ -1.43402237075119, 51.951767554897998 ], [ -1.431390624766249, 51.955117049787923 ], [ -1.429698111077124, 51.959179082641825 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 17000.0, "end": 18000.0, "scale": 1.0428695878e-05 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.429698111077124, 51.959179082641825 ], [ -1.428998128416302, 51.960859041027796 ], [ -1.431629874401244, 51.964687035187708 ], [ -1.43043362622627, 51.966840281902662 ], [ -1.431405181482281, 51.967983288086202 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 18000.0, "end": 19000.0, "scale": 1.0573304809e-05 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.431405181482281, 51.967983288086202 ], [ -1.438252965636922, 51.976039504738722 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "beg": 19000.0, "end": 19046.579963891814, "scale": 1.0446633156e-05 }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -1.438252965636922, 51.976039504738722 ], [ -1.438568113816088, 51.976410267302448 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find sample data for ogrlineref at gdal test data: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/autotest/utilities/data - path.shp and mstones.shp

An example of ogrlineref using is in test case: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_ogrlineref.py

`dist` column holds the distance in meters (for example this may be milestones value). The references.shp holds points with X and Y coordinates, and `dist` field hold meters along path (milestone).

Using `create` switch you create special vector layer which can used in conversion from spatial X,Y coordinates to meters (or kilometers etc.) and vice versa.

You can read about LRS at [grass wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Linear_Reference_System), [ESRI help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm).